# hide drop down field when specific email (@abc.com or @xyz.com) is inputted

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm building a registration form and I need to hide a drop down field when a specific email is inputted.  So when a user with email id of john**@abc.com** is added the drop will disappear.  I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#email").keyup(function(){
    $("#dropdown").toggle($(this).val() != "john*@abc.com");    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/hnRxm/